# How can I simulate NAT reflection failure with `iptables`?

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

Let's say that:

- My workstation LAN IP is 192.168.0.101
- My WAN IP is 12.34.56.78.
- My consumer-grade router is port-forwarding WAN:80 to 192.168.0.101:8080
- NAT Reflection / Hairpinning is working

So if I listen to 8080 on my workstation...

```sh
nc -l -p 8080
```

And I talk to it from *itself*, by it's external ip, it works ...

```sh
echo 'Hello World' | nc 12.34.56.78 80
```

And if kill and repeat `nc -l -p 8080` and talk to it from an external network, across the internet, it will also works ...

```sh
echo 'Hello World' | nc 12.34.56.78 80
```

But ...

### I want to *simulate* a hairpin failure

- my workstation *artificially* **CAN'T** talk to itself via the WAN IP
- something across the internet *CAN* still talk to it

How can I use `iptables` to create a rule that will simulate the NAT hairpin failure, but continue to allow *true* external traffic?

Comment: Cant you just drop outgoing packets to your WAN IP on the client computer ?

Comment: Yes. I'm getting old and my brain is so full of stuff I can't think anymore. That would be the simple, obvious solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Add an ordinary 'DROP' rule that blocks 'INPUT' packets from your router's IP address to this port.

Due to the way hairpinning "solves" the underlying problem, all hairpinned connections appear as if they come from the gateway (and there is no way to distinguish your own connections from someone else in your LAN's), but that *shouldn't* be happening to non-hairpinned connections – they will retain their original Internet source IP address.